# Why static_cast doesn't cast to the class which has been initialized

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

I want to cast the data to class instance using `static_cast`. Strangely it always cast's to base class and not the sub class which is initialized. Here is the example code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void Display () {
        fprintf(stderr, "I am A\n");
    }
};

class B : public  A
{
public:
    void Display () {
        fprintf(stderr, "I am B\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    B *b=new B();
    b->Display(); //Invokes subclass function
    A *a=static_cast<A*>(b);
    a->Display(); //Invokes baseclass function
}
```

Current Output:

```
I am B
I am A
```

Expected Output:

```
I am B
I am B
```

Comment: You want to use `virtual` methods.

Comment: Aah..! worked thanks a lot :)

Comment: And, incidentally, you don't need a cast there.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yeah i know, this was just a small part from the bigger code. to simplify my problem i have out like this.